# txt file chat system

Tags: php, facebook, generics, chat

I have this simple friend-to-friend Facebook style chat system on my site. When user starts a conversation with friend, new .txt file is created and named based on the ID's of the users, for example 142and153.txt. This is where all the messages are saved. Obviously this creates a huge security risk because everybody could see this conversation by entering www.website.com/142and153.txt. How can I hide the files from public? My website is almost finished and the last thing I want is that it contains security risks like this, so can you guys think of other problems with this kind of chat system, or should I just develop other kind of system?

Comment: If you insist on saving the info in text files, you should at least save them in a directory that is inaccessible by the Web browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can achieve that by considering couple of things:

1. create a new blank index.html in the directory where your chat files are being saved to avoid intruders to check out what files are there
2. try to use MD5 function for the files name, by md5(id1andid2) you can simply generate a 32 digit hexadecimal number based on the real id of the users, and that 'I believe' is very hard to predict.